# How to use Kentor AuthService to get additional assertion attributes

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, claims-based-identity, kentor-authservices

I'm using Kentor HttpModule in WebForms based application.
I need to get additional information asserted with loggin. I'm not sure, but I think that Kentor parse only attributeID="userId", and I need to get few more attributes.

Do I need to fork and modify Kentor in order to have these values available in my application, or they are stored somewhere.

I see the collection of xmlElements returned from AllAssertionElementNodes method in Saml2Response but I don't know how to access them in app.

To access ID I'm using this extension method:

```
public static string GetNameID(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var claimsIndentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(claimsIndentity)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var providerQuery = from c in claimsIndentity.Claims
                            where c.Type.EndsWith("/identity/claims/nameidentifier")
                            select c.Value;

        var provider = providerQuery.FirstOrDefault();

        return provider;
    }
```

And this:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 {
     userId = User.Identity.GetNameID();
 }
```

Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**

I believe this is a proper solution. Inside the ***ProcessResponse*** method in ***AcsCommand*** we have a ***samlResponse*** InnerXML, from there we can parse wanted data, create additional claims, or whatever, so now I have a solution (workaround maybe for my problem). Is there any other more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kentor.AuthServices SP translates all attributes in the assertion to claims. If you set a breakpoint in your `GetNameID` method and inspect the `claimsIdentity.Claims` enumeration all attributes should be there. If they're not, please file an issue on the [AuthService github page](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices).

Comment: Yep, they are there. Thanks a lot! That's more elegant solution than mine. I wrote a custom parser to pull them from response XML. Also I didn't see that you in IdP solution use the same logic, to translate all additional claims into attributes. Is there any downside of transforming all claims as attributes and vice verse? I mean for my case that will work fine, but generally speaking?

Comment: No, attributes and claims are really just two names for the same thing. In the rare cases where claims need to be filtered, that can be done with a `ClaimsAuthenticationManager`.

Comment: Can I also access saml2:Subject saml2:NameID value somehow without making my own parser?

Comment: The NameID is also translated into a claim.

Comment: Where's that in code?

I see that all statements are translated into attributes, and attributes to claims. But for this subject that subject is used just to generate XElement.

Comment: I mean I see it added as claim but in StubIdp, but I'm not interested in that, I can't find how it's translated from response into a claim.

Comment: Please post a new question for that - follow up questions are hard to discuss in comments.

Comment: Ok, created here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216083/kentor-authservice-read-subject-nameid