# Kentor AuthService - Read Subject NameID

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

How can I access to saml2:NameID from saml2:Subject response XML node by using Kentor AuthService?

I couldn't find in code anything that deals with that part of XML. Maybe I'm missing something.

I'm not asking about Kentor IdP, I see that there NameID is sent as additional claim, which is translated as attribute, I'm asking in general, IdP does not have to be powered by Kentor, so I can't rely that I will have this value passed as attribute.

So, if it's handled I couldn't find it here:
https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/tree/master/Kentor.AuthServices

One option can be to parse XML on my own, but if there's already implemented or better solution that will be great.

Answer (score 2):

The Subject NameID is translated to a claim with type `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` (`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier`).

It should be in the claims collection of the created claims identity.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have that from IdP, I have this https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7235433cc975fb4b8f56

Comment: That should give a Claim with value `TEST`. Do you get any claims at all?